# When including multiple files, returning an array, i get the first included array merged into the second include, why?

Tags: php, arrays

I have many .php files, that all should return an array of diffrent keys and values, and i want to include every single .php file, returning there coresponding array, into one big multi-dimensinel array, like this:

```
$array
    'file1.php' = ['something' => 'someValue'],
    'file2.php' = ['somethingElse' => 'someValue']
```

I do it by making a foreach .php file and include the file into $array[$filename], but file2.php array get merged with file1.php so what i get is this:

```
$array
    'file1.php' = ['something' => 'someValue'],
    'file2.php' = ['something' => 'someValue', 'somethingElse' => 'someValue']
```

I dont understand why?
Here is my example code:

file1.php:

```
$array = ['something' => 'someValue'];
return $array;
```

file2.php

```
$array = ['somethingElse' => 'someValue'];
    return $array;
```

test.php

```
$array[1] = include_once "/var/www/html/folder/file1.php";
$array[2] = include_once "/var/www/html/folder/file2.php";
print_r($array);
```

And the output is:

```
$array
    1 = ['something' => 'someValue'],
    2 = ['something' => 'someValue', 'somethingElse' => 'someValue']
```

And the expected output:

```
$array
    1 = ['something' => 'someValue'],
    2 = ['somethingElse' => 'someValue']
```

How can I archive this output instead? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have same variable names everywhere.

Comment: Aaah, now i understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

file*.php:

```php
return ['something' => 'someValue'];
```

Explanation: the inclusion rewrites the $array variable.

You could  also use this:

```php
function get_include_array($filename) {
return include_once"/var/www/html/folder/$filename";
}
```

because function uses not-global variables

Comment: Aaah thank you very much, i understand now. In production i do like this: foreach (glob('/var/www/html/folder/*.php') as $filepath) and include every filepath to $array[$filename]